# ngShow is not working for a particular div

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-show, ng-hide

In the AngularJS the ng-show function is not working in the div part

```
ng-show="false"
```

Here is the code for it http://plnkr.co/edit/jEuOmxR67kwO8tOeSz3g?p=preview
as you can see in the line 84 I have included ng-show but still it is showing in the output.

Answer (score 2):

You have missed to define ng-app in the root element.

```
<html ng-app="">
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize it as aangular application .In the second line make it as `<html ng-app="">`

Answer (score 0):

you're missing to include default ng-hide class here. Please try to include class with value ng-hide.

```
<div ng-show="false" class="ng-hide">
```

Updated the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/y7EMzX8gCw39WT9amyfO?p=info.